# How can I debug my infinite 8-queens program?

Tags: c++, debugging, logic, n-queens

I translated the program from an earlier version that used go-to statements, but somewhere my logic got muddled up because it prints an infinite loop of boards where the only piece is a queen in row 0, column 0.

How can I find the bug?

```
bool rowCheck(int board[], int column);
bool diagonalCheck(int board[], int column);
void print (int board[]);

int main(){
    int queens[8];
    int col = 0;
    queens[0] = 0;

    while(col > -1){
        //if current column moves beyond 8th column, print solution and
        if(col == 8){
            print(queens);                          
            col--;  
        }
        //if current row moves beyond the 8th row, resets row to -1 and moves back to previous column;                                                                              
        if(queens[col] == 8){                       
            queens[col] = -1;                       
            col--;                                  
        }
        //if the current board checks true for all columns prior, moves to next column
        else if( rowCheck(queens, col) && diagonalCheck(queens, col) ){
            col++;
        }
        //moves queen to the next row of current column
        else{
            queens[col]++;
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
//checks previous rows for an adjacent queen
bool rowCheck(int board[] , int column){
    for(int i = 0; i < column; i++){
        if(board[i] == board[column])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
//checks previous rows for queens diagonally
bool diagonalCheck(int board[], int column){
    for(int i = 0; i < column; i++){
        if((column - i) == abs(board[column] - board[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
//print
void print(int board[]){
    static int solution = 0; 
    solution++;
    cout << "Solution " << solution << endl;
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < 8; column++)   
            if(board[column] == row)
                cout << "1 ";
            else
                cout << "0 ";

        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Step thru this in your debugger; it should be easy to figure out.  Hint: there's a problem with `rowCheck`, which you are calling with `rowCheck(queens, 0)`.

Comment: Hint:  Add some diagnostic print statements.  This will help show the behavior during runtime.  You may also want to add a depth gauge -- a variable that indicates the recursion depth.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to initialize the `queens` array. It contains garbage values except the first element, which is properly initialized as 0. As a result, your queens are positioned outside the board (most probably), and `rowCheck` and `diagonalCheck` functions fail to find conflicting quens. You should initialize the whole array.